# What is perfect elimination bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am not a Maths guy, and  I was required to read a paper on Graph Theory.
Now after few pages the definition of perfect elimination bipartite graph comes up, no matter how hard I try grasp the meaning I could not put it together.
Heres the definition
[image: Definition]
I understand individual parts but couldn't put it together. Too many abstract symbols and I couldn't find anything google too.
Can anyone please what it is actually in simpler words with example.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you already familiar with the non-bipartite version of these definitions?

Comment: Wow never occurred  to me surely read about them, and tell if I get it. Thank you.